# how to enable touch in carplay simulator

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am running my app on the CarPlay simulator, but it is not supporting any touch and also not showing the tabbar. I have added the com.apple.developer.playable-content entitlement. Is there any other entitlement that needs to be added in order to work with touch on CarPlay simulator. FYI the default message app takes works with the touch.

Comment: I have same problem

Answer (score 9):

After several days of hard work. I finally get this working.

1) **Set entitlement in your project**

```
<key>com.apple.developer.carplay-protocols</key> <array> <string>com.brand.carplay.feature</string> </array>
```

2) **Activate the CarPlay window in Terminal**

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator CarPlay -bool YES
```

3) **Activate extra options**

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator CarPlayExtraOptions -bool YES
```

4) **Add your CarPlay protocol to iPhone Simulator**

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator CarPlayProtocols -array-add com.brand.carplay.feature
```

You should clean project and delete app from iOS Simulator. After that - touch screen and UITabBarController are working in my application.

Comment: is there new settings or configuration required for iOS 13 CarPlay apps? I am facing issue .. my application not appearing on ios 13 CarPlay simulator but it works on ios 12 simulator.

Comment: I sent a feedback to Apple one month ago and they fixed it now. It was a bug. It's working now on Xcode 11.3 beta.

Comment: removing app from iOS simulator and then installing fresh helped me to make CarPlay simulator responding to touches :) thanks!

Comment: Doing the "Erase All Content and Settings" for my iOS simulator, and then restarting the simulator and carplay fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

after following the steps from @kubacizek, select `I/O` > `External Displays...` > `CarPlay` in the simulator.

you then get a pop-up that lets you enable touch. you can also enable some other hardware buttons

[image]